Gradle Fails Random Unit Tests on CI
We are using Kubernetes GitLab Runners on CI to build, test Gradle tasks. We have 48 cores on each runner pod and I set --max-workers=24 to unit test task. I observed memory consumption while unit test pipeline, on the peak it uses %70 of max. However, random unit tests are failing with error below.
MyStateTest > given item popUpText is not null, when getInfoText called, then should return expected FAILED
    kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncaughtExceptionsBeforeTest at TestScope.kt:238

What can be the problem? Thank you!
